# Laravel 5.1 with nginx no input file specififed

Tags: nginx, laravel-5.1

I am using a Nginx server and under the public directory i move a laravel 5.1 app and map into sites-available and sites-enabled.

When i try to access by URL it says "No input file file specified"

Is there a way to prevent this problem ?

[Updated] NGINX Config

```
server { 
    listen 80; listen [::]:80; 
    root /somedir/somewww/someapp/app/webroot/; 
    server_name someapp.com; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/someapp.access.log; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/someapp.error.log; 
    index index.php; 
    location / { 
                   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args; 
               } 
    include fastcgi_cluster.conf; 
}
```

Comment: This issue is definitely coming from your nginx config. Kindly include the code

Comment: this is the sites-available code : `server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /somedir/somewww/someapp/app/webroot/;
    server_name someapp.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/someapp.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/someapp.error.log;
    index index.php;
    location /
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
    include fastcgi_cluster.conf;
}`

Comment: For virtual host config into nginx.conf:` `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Comment: include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

Comment: For basic settings: `sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;`

Comment: are you certain that this path exists? `/somedir/somewww/someapp/app/webroot/` this should point to your laravel public folder

Comment: Yes i take care to that the path was checked and the server_name was checked they exists!

Comment: `no input file specififed` means its not pointing to the right folder, it can not find index.php file